# =IFERROR(VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-2016

i have this formula =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H4,Names!A:Q,16,0),"N/A") it works but only takes the top cell value and i need it to add up all cells in the row matching the value in "H4"

[table extracting data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fixm3.png)

[table extracting data too, where the formula in question is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4AvU.png)

here is the example, i need the rows connecting to "mac" to add together in a separate table cell eg: 19:00 = 31, 20:00 = 38

can anyone help with this?

Comment: I can help if you can provide an example of your data and of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Pleas mock up the minimal amount of data and expected output to demonstrate you question and post it as text(preferred) or photo in the original post using [edit]

Comment: Sorry Scott, @Jeeped is too quick for us.

Comment: @ashleedawg I hope it answered the question but the, `from multiple rows in the same column matching the merged cell`, is what concerns me.  Jeeped's answer may actually answer, but if there are merged cells to many values, it may not.  waiting and seeing.

Comment: You are going to want to fill a helper column with the correct name duplicated in each row.  Then you can use a SUMIFS, like below or a pivot table.

Comment: i have this formula to extraxct the data from cells "A" =IFERROR(INDEX($Z$3:$Z$43, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($U$1:U1, $Z$3:$Z$43&"") + IF(ISTEXT($Z$3:$Z$43)=FALSE,-1,0), 0)), "") which the cell in the formula in question "H4" is taking the data from. everything is working appart from the formula in question is not taking data from the adjacent cells with the meged cell in column "A"

Comment: 1.  Put clarifications in the Original Post using [Edit]. 2. You will need to create a column that has the a name for each row.  Merged cells only put the value in the upper left cell of the merged area.

Comment: i have added snips to help get an idea of what im trying to achieve

Comment: @ScottCraner - out of the three of us, you're definitely [the quickest overall](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/837174/quickest-answers?UserID=8112776,4039065,4851590), jeesh

Comment: i am still struggling with this one, if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
=sumifs(p:p, a:a, h4)
```

Comment: i cant seem to get this to work with what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you have merged cells in `Names!A:A` - so have brought problems on yourself. *One* solution is to **unmerge** (and avoid ever merging anything ever again!) and if you only want each `Name` to be shown the one time fill in the other instances but avoid displaying them (such as by blending the font colour into the background colour - such as with [Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877819/conditional-formatting-for-cells-when-cell-above-has-the-same-value/26877927#26877927)).

The filling in is easy with the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337482/sum-cell-range-filtered-by-merged-value).

Then @Jeeped's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740370/1505120) should serve, provided you qualify the ranges with the sheet name:

```
=SUMIFS(Names!P:P,Names!A:A,H4)
```